# Adding label/button to UICollectionView - Footer or not?

Tags: objective-c, uicollectionview

I have a collectionView that displays an array of images in a single, horizontal layout. I'm trying to add a UILabel under each cell. I assumed the best/easiest way to do this would be to add a footer view/supplementary view for each cell. Therefore, I'm overriding viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind. I have an array of images names that correlate to the array of images. So I'm just hoping the see the image name as the label for each each cell. However, all labels and names are overlapping on the first cell. Also, the footer view doesn't come into view until I scroll to the last image/cell, so I don't see the overlapping labels on the first cell until I scroll to the end. I know the issue is in my viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind implementation, but I'm not sure how to correct it. Can someone please advise? Thanks in advance!!

```
- (UICollectionReusableView *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:(NSString *)kind atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
NSLog(@"viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind");

static NSString *FooterCellIdentifier = @"FooterView"; // string value identifier for cell reuse
FooterViewCell *footerView;
if (kind == UICollectionElementKindSectionFooter) {
    NSLog(@"*******Element Kind is a footer!*******");
    footerView = [collectionView dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind:UICollectionElementKindSectionFooter
                                                                    withReuseIdentifier:FooterCellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    for (int i = 0; i < [self.imagesArray count]; i++) {
        UILabel *testLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.myCollectionView.frame.origin.x/2, self.myCollectionView.frame.origin.y/2, CellWidth, 20)];
        //testLabel.text = [self.imageNames objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        testLabel.text = self.imageNames[i];
        [self.myCollectionView addSubview:testLabel];
    }

     return footerView;
} else {
    NSLog(@"*******Element Kind is NOT a footer!*******");
    return nil;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Header and footer views on `UICollectionView` are only relative to sections.

Since the labels are supposed to identify the images (the model), you should build your `UICollectionViewCell` with the label and image view inside, as subviews. The easiest way is doing it inside a storyboard, with prototype cells on the collection view.

[image: Collection view with a prototype cell]

Comment: The labels were really just a test to get it displayed. Ultimately, I'll be adding a UIButton for each image, where tapping the button would correlate to the specific cell/image, which is why I thought of doing it via the supplementary view. Does your answer still apply? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, still applies. But I must warn you that adding a button inside a cell would interfere with the standard action of the cell; Unless you want the button to have a different behavior than the one the user has by tapping on the cell.

Comment: That's the thing, I don't really want it inside the cell. I want it below the cell. That's why I thought I needed to use supplementary view, so I would have access to the indexpath of the cell.

Comment: But by doing that, you are unnecessarily making it more complex, because you have a relationship of the buttons with the model. Can you clarify what you are trying to do with the button?

Comment: The button will basically save the related image to a user's profile which is why having access to the indexpath of the cell is crucial. I understand your suggestion and how much easier that would be. I just don't know how I would do it that way without having the button overlaying the image/cell.

Comment: Just change the cell's size to accommodate the button, and position the button below the image view. I added a screenshot the my answer.

Comment: Thanks, but I do not want the button as part of the cell. I know this can be done. This is a very common thing, i.e. having a UI item for each image/cell. I also have a border outlining the cell and that would clearly indicate the button is inside the cell, even if I position the image above the button. Not what I want.

Comment: It's a common thing having all that is pertaining to the object inside the cell. Even more because you have all the flexibility to configure a cell and its contents, including the borders. Having something inside the cell and other outside, but both relative to the object of the data source, is not common and does not make any sense. You will be adding a huge amount of complexity to your code unnecessarily. Good luck.

Comment: Galrito - I think you may be right. I was able to get the labels laid out close to how I want. With a little more work, I'd be able to get it right. However, an additional issue I encountered is that they would not appear until I scrolled to the last image. Apparently, this is because supplemental views are really tied to sections and not the cells - as you mentioned above. Since I have 1 section displaying cells horizontally, that explains why this is happening. So bottom line, I think I need to follow your advice. Thanks!

Comment: Any suggestion on the best way to size the imageview inside the cell? Currently, the imageview is the same exact size as the cell itself. I guess I'll need to enlarge the cell a little bit and fit the imageview and the label and button inside it, per your advice. Thanks again!